# Graph partition

Tags: graph-theory

Given an directed Graph $G(V,E)$ and a source node $v \in V$. I need to find a partition for $G$ into two sets $X$ and $Y$ in such way that the nodes in $X$ are those that there is a path from $v$ to each of them, and the nodes $Y$ are those that there is no path.

Now, I can use a Depth-first search with $v$ as source node and put the result nodes into $X$ and the other nodes into $Y$ and connect the two sets with the remaining edges. But I want to know if there is an optimal algorithm if exists to do that. (Sorry, I am new into Graph Theory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DFS is optimal algorithm for this problem. Breadth-first search (BFS) is another optimal algorithm. Both of them take time proportional to the sum of number of vertices and the number of arcs outgoing from $X$ if graph is directed or the number of edges with both ends in $X$ if graph is undirected. This is obviously the best possible time. This bound is true if you use [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) for graph storing. If you use adjacency matrix both algorithms become slower, but take $O(|X|\cdot|G|)$ of time that is the best possible in this case.

Comment: Thanks . But I want to know if there is an optimal algorithm for the partition part. not the search one .

Comment: As I've said partition problem can't be solved faster, since you need to observe all edges with at least one end in $X$ (and therefore both ends in $X$) or all arcs outgoing from $X$.